# Do drugs that increase (or don't decrease) mortality during clinical studies still get approved and if so - why?

Tags: clinical-study, life-expectancy

From reading about clinical studies on various chronic diseases, I get a sense that increasing lifespan is rarely the primary objective of these studies, and instead they focus on surrogate markers, like blood pressure or blood sugar. Is it generally important for a drug to have a reduced mortality compared to placebo for it to be approved by FDA, etc?